# Delete path with size smaller than 0.7mm in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, illustrator-scripting

I have a traced image in Illustrator with many smaller shapes. I want minimum 0.7mm size for every shape. Is there any way to delete or increase size of all shapes that are smaller than 0.7mm?

Answer (score 3):

There's a "[select objects by size](https://js4ai.blogspot.com/2009/02/new-script-select-paths-by-size.html)" script that might be what you're looking for

Comment: A more direct link to the script: https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/SelectPathsBySize.jsx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Illustrator offers no ability whatsoever to select objects based upon dimensions. You *may* be able to write a script for such a thing. But nothing "easy" exists.